# URL re-writing in ASP.NET C# using IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I do not understand very much about IIS but I am trying to do a redirect with URL rewriting. 
I am trying to do a redirect from 
http://www.cooltoys.com.au/besttoys to http://www.cooltoys.com.au/bestcooltoys

I have got the following code in my Web.config file and it doesn't work and i'm having difficulty understanding why.

```
<rules>
<rule name = "ToysRedirect" StopProcessing="true" />
<match url = "besttoys" />
<action type = "Redirect" url = "http://www.cooltoys.com.au/bestcooltoys" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
</rules>
```

I think the problem is in the "match url" part (Pattern) so can someone please explain how to write this so it redirects correctly.
Thanks,
Corey

Comment: I know this doesn't specifically answer your question but this might help you a little more going forward http://www.amazon.co.uk/Learn-Windows-IIS-Month-Lunches/dp/1617290971

Comment: Also please dont flag this as already answered, I am aware of the other similar questions but they did not help with my problem

Answer (score 1):

It will be something like:

```
<rules>
    <rule name = "ToysRedirect" StopProcessing="true" />
    <match url = "^(.*)/besttoys$" />
    <action type = "Redirect" url = "{R:1}/bestcooltoys" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
```

Basically you need to learn regular expressions. "^(.*)/besttoys$" - means that the we look for any url that will end with /besttoys and then we replace it with /bestcooltoys. The () chars define a group which we can then refer to by {R:1} - means first defined group.